# "Operand type clash" with DATE column

Tags: sql-server-2008

I enter the following command into the SQL Server Management Studio

```
insert into testtable ([product_name], [price], [expire_date], [expire_time]) 
  values ('Teapot', 10.00, 23/12/2012, '12:35:00')
```

It yields this error:

> Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

These are the columns:

```
  Column name   |   datatype
----------------+---------------
product_name    | varchar(30)
price           | money
expire_date     | date
expire_time     | time(7)
```

Comment: 23/12/2012 is treated like a math expression (and its overall type is integer).  Quote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use string delimiters around date literals, and do whatever you can to avoid ambiguous, regional formats like `DD/MM/YYYY`. How about:

```
insert into dbo.testtable ([product_name], [price], [expire_date], [expire_time]) 
  values ('Teapot', 10.00, '20121223', '12:35:00');
```

I use `YYYYMMDD` because, except with `DATE`, `YYYY-MM-DD` can be misinterpreted. With `DATETIME`, for example:

```
SET LANGUAGE FRENCH;
DECLARE @d DATETIME = '2012-12-23';
```

Result:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3
> La conversion d'un type de données varchar en type de données datetime a créé une valeur hors limites.

Your original format could also cause problems even with date:

```
SET DATEFORMAT MDY;
DECLARE @d DATE = '23/12/2012';
```

Result:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Not to sound preachy, but please see this blog post:

- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

And this video:

- [Recommended SQL Server Date Formats](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9315/recommended-sql-server-date-formats/)

And Tibor's excellent article:

- [The ultimate guide to the datetime datatypes](http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes)

Comment: Great answer. Never thought that your answer also include example and their result. Thanks.